# How can I prevent passing in multiple parameters to controller?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Right now I have a form that contains 6 security questions and 6 security answers. I've been trying to refactor my code and I'm running into an interesting situation that I'm not sure on how to proceed.

Here's my view:

```
var RequestSecurityQuestions_Submit = function () {

        ValidationAttribute.BlankValue(true);
        var form = $('form#RequestSecurityQuestions');
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);

        var d = $('form#RequestSecurityQuestions').serialize();
        SecurityQuestionsValid = true;

        var inputs = $('form#RequestSecurityQuestions').find('input[data-val]');
        $.each(inputs, function (index) {
            var input = inputs[index];
            if (!$(input).valid()) {
                SecurityQuestionsValid = false;
            }
        });

        var dataObject = {}, dropdowns = $("input.customdropdownlist");

    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        dataObject['question' + i] = $(dropdowns[i]).data("kendoDropDownList").value()
    }

    for (var i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
        dataObject['answer' + i] = $('#idAnswer' + i).val();
    }

    var dataToPass = JSON.stringify(dataObject);

        if (SecurityQuestionsValid) {

            $.ajax({
                url: Url.getFullUrl('Account/RequestSecurityQuestions_Submit'),
                type: 'Post',
                data: { securityInfo: dataToPass },
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {

                    //Next Dialog
                },
                error: AjaxLog.HandleAjaxCallFail
            });
        }
        return SecurityQuestionsValid;
    }
```

I get a dataObject which contains all the values from my view and I want to pass it to the controller.

Currently this works:

```
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult RequestSecurityQuestions_Submit(string answer1, string answer2, string answer3, string answer4, string answer5, string answer6, string question1, string question2, string question3, string question4, string question5, string question6)
        {
            SecurityQuestions securityQuestions = new SecurityQuestions();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(answer1))
            {
                securityQuestions.ChallengeA1 = answer1;
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(answer2))
            {
                securityQuestions.ChallengeA2 = answer2;
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(answer3))
            {
                securityQuestions.ChallengeA3 = answer3; 
            }
            //etc....
}
```

However, I am passing in 12 parameters to my controller which sounds like a no-no to me. Is there another way to pass in my data from my view to my controller without having to pass in 12 parameters?

EDIT:

New controller attempt:

```
/*Problem: securityInfo array looks like: ""{\"question0\":\"2\",\"question1\":\"3\",\"question2\":\"4\",\"question3\":\"5‌​\",\"question4\":\"7\",\"question5\":\"1\",\"answer1\":\"fgfg\",\"answer2\":\"fgf‌​gf\",\"answer3\":\"fgfg\",\"answer4\":\"fgfgfg\",\"answer5\":\"fgfg\",\"answer6\"‌​:\"fggf\"}"" */

[AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult RequestSecurityQuestions_Submit(string[] securityInfo)
        {
            SecurityQuestions securityQuestions = new SecurityQuestions();

}
```

Comment: Just use a model containing the 12 properties `public string answer1 { get; set; } public string answer2 { get; set; }` etc and use `public ActionResult RequestSecurityQuestions_Submit(yourModel model)`

Comment: I think I tried that but I was getting null and 0 values :S

Comment: Your client code should be updated also, send dataType application/json and the data is a json object contains all 12 properties.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use an array? It's perfectly valid and common to use the same name for multiple request parameters if they hold the same type of data.

Comment: Should work fine but its hard to understand exactly what this script is doing. `$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);` is nonsense and does nothing. Why do you do `var d = $('form#RequestSecurityQuestions').serialize();` which would correctly serialize your form and post back and correctly bind to your model, but then throw it away and try and construct the name/value pairs manually?

Comment: I posted an answer that will function, similar to what Haz proposed, but Stephens question is good, there is a more elegant way to trim your code and send data back and forth!

Comment: @KalaJ, I suspect you have a classic x-y problem. If you construct your view correctly based on a model, then you can post back that model. Almost all of the code in you script is unnecessary - all that would be required is `$.post('@Url.Action("RequestSecurityQuestions_Submit", "Account"), $('form').serialize(), function(data) { //Next Dialog });`

Comment: @StephenMuecke, some of it is necessary, the other stuff I will clean up. I need some of the validation because I'm checking if the form is valid before submission. But you're right some of the other stuff is not necessary, I apologize. I have one issue though where the dataobject I pass into my controller is in a form of a giant string of parameters instead of 12 parameters inside an array.

Comment: If you have client side validation enabled and have included the relevant scripts, then its all done out of the box anyway

Comment: Re your edit- that wont work - your parameter is `string[] securityInfo` which means in order to bind you would need to post securityInfo=someValue&securityInfo=anotherValue&securityInfo=`...etc. Construct you view properly based on a model using strongly typed html helpers and let the framework handle it automatically for you.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, maybe I'm missing something. Let me go back to the drawing board to where I first had it. I have a dataObject (non Json stringified) and I pass it to my controller. I use SecurityQuestions securityQuestions model to pass into my controller BUT all the values were null, why?

Comment: @KalaJ, Your need to show your model and the view (just part of it - one of 2 properties is enough)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, this might help a little: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/94657/selecting-security-questions-and-entering-answers This approach works perfectly but not best practice. needs to be refactored.

Comment: Why are you using MVC if your just going to ignore all its features including 2-way model binding, client and server side validation and instead write all this awful code?

Comment: I'm sorry Stephen, there is tons of spaghetti code in this current project I'm in and yes, it sucks. This is how some of the other examples do it, who knows if it's needed. Sorry to offend.

Comment: @KalaJ, I'm not offended :) I just don't understand why your doing this. If you show part of your model and view then I can help you.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, nevermind. Daniel helped me out and we got it working :)

Comment: @KalaJ, Need a break for a few hours but will look at it later - Can I assume you want to post back the value of `ChallengeQ1Id (the question)` and `ChallengeA1` (the answer), and that there are 6 question/answers. (ChallengeQ2Id/ChallengeA2 etc). (And irrespective of Daniel's answer, its just a hack to fix what are major problems with your code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve this of course, the following is one of them. A better one would be to restructure your code as per other answers/comments.

```
// Creating your array
var dataObject = [], 

dropdowns = $("input.customdropdownlist");

//Populate your array. [0-5] will be questions and [6-11] will be answers .

    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        if (i < 6){
            dataObject[i] = $(dropdowns[i]).data("kendoDropDownList").value()
        }
        else {
            var d = i - 5;
            dataObject[i] = $('#idAnswer' + d).val();
        }
    }

// Your AJAX call with contentType

            $.ajax({
                url: Url.getFullUrl('Account/RequestSecurityQuestions_Submit'),
                type: 'Post',
                data: JSON.Stringify(dataObject), //Change data format to JSON array, will be received as array in backend
                contentType: "application/json",
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {

                    //Next Dialog
                },
                error: AjaxLog.HandleAjaxCallFail
            });
```

And simply receive the array in your backend

```
public ActionResult RequestSecurityQuestions_Submit(List<String> data)
        {
//Your code here
        }
```

Comment: and for the array, I would access it like securityQuestions.ChallengeA1 = answers[0], for example?

Comment: Yes, the general way you access any array =)

Comment: what you trying  it not very nice in practice... though it may work if you spend more time on it

Comment: Opp sorry, I meant to say, I kept stringifying the dataObject but I had to remove ContentType and dataType for it to work but it's one long string passed to my controller. How can I pass it in to access the array indexing?

Comment: Changed the creation of your "array" Object to describe the key value pairing you are looking for.

Comment: dataObject['answer' + i] = $(dropdowns[i]).data("kendoDropDownList").value()

Comment: that doesn't make sense @DanielHoffmann-Mitscherling, the answers should not be value to my dropdown values. I have "two sets of data",6 questions (6 questions selected from dropdownlist) and 6 answers (typed in by user). Please see my edit.

Comment: Damn, that simplifies things a lot. When you create var dataObject = {} here you are creating an object. If you do not need key value pairings, you can just an array, via dataObject = []. Then your indices in your array will compare with your answers in the DOM elements on the page. Try the edited answer please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81591/discussion-between-daniel-hoffmann-mitscherling-and-kala-j).

Answer (score 1):

Mate, Well, I don't understand why you have N parameters which has the same type of data--- that's really where the class should come for.

Short Answer will be you can create a Model which contains these parameters, then on your controller, just RequestSecurityQuestions_Submit(Model postedModel)

then access your parameters inside like postedModel.parameter1 ... In you ajax call , it looks like

```
 $.ajax({
            url: Url.getFullUrl('Account/RequestSecurityQuestions_Submit'),
            type: 'Post',
            data: {parameter1:'',parameter2:''...},
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {

                //Next Dialog
            },
```

Multiple parameter(n>3) on any function is bad in theory and practice,

Comment: wait, I don't want to have multiple parameters passed to my data?

Comment: in practice, you want pass a model which wrapping alll the data you need to a controller, then you can do validation on your model, much simpler. Also your view can be strong typed view with Model

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify all this by correctly using a model, binding to a model and posting back you model.

View models

```
public class SecurityAnswerVM
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Please select a question")]
    [Display(Name = "Question")]
    public int? QuestionID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter an answer")]
    public string Answer { get; set; }
}
public class SecurityLoginVM
{
    public SelectList QuestionList { get; set; }
    public List<SecurityAnswerVM> SelectedQuestions { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    SecurityLoginVM model = new SecurityLoginVM();
    // Populate SelectedQuestions and QuestionList from the database
    return View(model);
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(SecurityLoginVM model)
{
    // model.SelectedQuestions contains the 6 objects containing the QuestionID and the users Answer
    ....
}
```

EditorTemplate (`/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/SecurityAnswerVM.cshtml`)

```
@model yourAssembly.SecurityAnswerVM

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.QuestionID)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.QuestionID, (SelectList)ViewData["options"], "Please select", new { @class = "question" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.QuestionID)

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Answer)
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Answer)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Answer)
```

Main view

```
@model yourAssembly.SecurityLoginVM
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.SelectedQuestions, new { options = Model.QuestionList })
    <button id="save type="submit">Save</button> // or type="button" is posting via ajax
}
```

And if you want to use ajax to post the data

```
var url = '@Url.Action("Index")';
$('#save').click(function() {
    $.post(url, $('form').serialize(), function(data) {
        // Next Dialog
    });
});
```

Far less code, strongly typed model binding, client and server side validation and all the other beneficial features of using MVC!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll definitely take a look when I get back home :)

Comment: Hey Stephen, what if I had to do a check if all the answers entered were non duplicate. I would have to create an actionresult in my controller and return true or false depending if there were dups or not?

Comment: You could simply use `bool hasDuplicates = model.SelectedQuestions.GroupBy(x => x.Answer).Where(g => g.Count() > 1).Any();` which will return `true` if there are duplicates - and then return a json result indicating the error. And of course you can write a script to check this is the browser before you submit (and cancel the submit if there are duplcates

Comment: if I do server side validation and I want to display  an error validation warning, I would need to add a custom attribute to the viewmodel properties right?

Comment: No, that's not necessary at all (and it would not work anyway because it would need to be applied to the collection, but you cant bind to a collection - only to properties of the objects in the collection)

Comment: ohhh ok. So, then let's say I just want to do server side validation but I want to display a qtip error with text specific to that error when validation, fails, how do I do that?

Comment: We are getting off track with respect to your question, but since your POST method appears to be returning json (you have not shown it !), then  use the `bool hasDuplicates = ..` code above followed by `if (hasDuplicates) { return json(new { hasDuplicates = true };` and in the script - `$.post(...) { if (data.hasDuplicates) { // display error }) else if (...`

Comment: Ohhh ok. I will give it a try. Thank you. If I have question on best practice or something else, I will open another question. Thank you Stephen!

Comment: See the new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31122271/show-qtip-for-specific-textfields-that-contain-duplicates

Answer (score 0):

Why not doing something like this -

```
    public class QA {
         public int QId {get;set;}
         public string Answer {get;set;}
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RequestSecurityQuestions_Submit(QA[] answers)
    {
        for (var qa in answers){
             //do what ever you like
        }
    }
```

and then in js -

```
// Creating your array
var dataObject = [], 
var dropdowns = $("input.customdropdownlist");
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    dataObject[i] = {
        'QId': $(dropdowns[i]).data("kendoDropDownList").value(),
        'Answer': dataObject[i] = $('#idAnswer' + i).val();
    };
}


$.ajax({
    url: Url.getFullUrl('Account/RequestSecurityQuestions_Submit'),
    type: 'Post',
    data: JSON.stringify(dataObject),
    contentType: "application/json",
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
    },
    error: function(data){
    }
});
```